# WP7 RootFrame with two different Objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, agfx

I'm using the AGFX framework in my WP7 app. To use it I need to set the following in my `App.xaml.cs`

```
RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrameEx();
```

Now I want to add the page transitions from Silverlight Toolkit for WP7. To make them work **also** I need to change my RootFrame as an specific element

```
RootFrame = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TransitionFrame();
```

How should I solve this problem? I cannot use both...or there is any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly assign both to the same `RootFrame`. Still, the source code of these two classes is available, so you can create a frame inheriting from `PhoneApplicationFrameEx` and add the logic from the `TransitionFrame` (or the other way around).